# XSL and namespaces

Tags: xslt

Parsing the following with the php xlst processor result in this error:

```
`Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Namespace prefix g on id is not defined in /var/www    /mistermatic/spider/resources/xslt/car/google.xsl, line: 32 in /var/www/mistermatic/ads/PublicXML/makeXML.php on line 91`
```

How do I correctly define the namespace inside the rss node so that I can apply it to all the children I'm gonna manipulate?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
            <channel>
        <title>Mistermatic</title>
        <link>http://www.mistermatic.it</link>
        <description>Multipubblicazione di annunci di automobili nuove ed usate</description>

                <xsl:for-each select="//ad">
                    <item xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="itemId"/>
                        <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
                        <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[Veicoli a motore > Veicoli > Auto, autocarri e furgoni]]></g:google_product_category>
                    </item>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="itemId">
        <g:id>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
        </g:id>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `xmlns:g` declaration up to the `xsl:stylesheet` element, making it visible throughout the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are defining the namespace within your `rss` element, however, it is used elsewhere in your XSLT file. Try moving your namespace definition to the root of your XSLT document.

Comment: Ok, moving in the root the xlmns declaration like this: `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">` I get this by php: Warning: XSLTProcessor::importStylesheet(): xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported in etc etc!!! what can I do to define the google xmlns at version 2.0 and keep xsl xmlns at version 1.0?

Comment: Leave `version="2.0"` on the rss element, only move `xmnls:g`.